# Which electrical freight bicycle would you recommend?

Tags: electric-bike, luggage

I am looking for a bicycle to make my car redundant for weekly groceries.

A typical Saturday trip would be to the department store(5 km) then to my parents for delivery (20 km) then to another shop (20 km) then back home (5 km), with a up to 45 kg of luggage.

The possibility to fix the dog in it or in the future to transport grand children would be an asset.

I was thinking of [Larry vs Harry.com](https://larryvsharry.com) or [Urban Arrow](https://Urbanarrow.com).

- Any experience with these makes?
- Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean Urban Arrow rather than City Arrow? That link isn't working for me. Other popular brands include Butchers & Bicycles, and Riese & Muller.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I edited the question.

Comment: You might also consider getting a regular electric bike and pulling a trailer when you have large loads. The smaller lighter bike is easier to store and move around, and the weight when loaded is distributed across more wheels.

Comment: Check availability of servicing in your area.  I live in a pretty decent sized city and still there's only one place that services Shimano Steps and even they will just send it away for anything major.  Whereas multiple shops have techs who can strip and service Bosch units.  A different city may be the opposite.

Comment: I found two shops within walking distance. Sorry to make you jalous.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly these kinds of shopping questions tend to be closed as off-topic because they directly compare two things, and the answers only have a short shelf life.

---

My general advise is the same for any bike.  It must be **comfortable for you**, and fit you, and suit the environment in which you intent to use it.  That means getting a leg over and test-riding both.

Try and spend at least a short time on leg power only, before using the electrics.  You might feel differently about the options depending on that.

Extra thoughts about a cargo bike

- They're not small - do you have room to store it?
- They're not cheap - can you store it securely?  Cargo bikes are desirable and attract thieves.
- Even unloaded cargo bikes tend to be heavy.  Will that be an issue (ie do you have stairs etc)
- For the special loads, you'll want a bench seat, possibly removable. and a couple of seatbelts.   For the dog, you'll want an eyebolt or similar in the middle of the floor to secure a walking lead, to stop dog jumping over either side.
- Insurance - does yours cover a pricy cargo bike?
- Batteries - they tend to not last as long when the bike weight increases.  Make sure you can either fit several, or at least carry enough spares to swap.  On the flip side, its a bike, so ultimately you can pedal it without battery.  Thus "range anxiety" is less of an issue than an electric car where you're otherwise stranded.

  - Remember Batteries are consumables - make sure you can still buy them in the future.  They're not cheap either.

Comment: Is it too late to push for an edit on the question to something more like "what are the pros/cons of long-tails, long johns, trikes and trailers".

Comment: @thosphor  Worth checking - we have https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cargo  but there's no "what are the pros and cons of different cargo bike designs?"  So that might make a good question on its own.  It would promote very long answers though.